# C# HttpRequestMessage.GetCorrelationId method returns duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, audit-trail

My team and I have been working on this issue for a couple of days and we can't determine the root cause why GetCorrelationId() returns duplicates GUID sometimes.

Within the application that I'm working right now we use the correlation id to tie up the request path.

For example the UI sends a Save request to the API in .NET. When the API calls the save method in the query service from the controller, it pass through the result of `Request.GetCorrelationId()` to the method call.

The save method in the query service uses this parameter to insert a new row in the audit_logs table with the request information.

The save method then calls other save methods on nested objects that belongs to the main Object, passing the correlation_id generated in the controller.

Something like this

```
[ Controller ]
var correlation_id = HttpRequestMessage.GetCorrelationId();
{
  ParentObject.save(correlation_id) -> {
    ChildObject1.save(correlation_id),
    ChildObject2.save(correlation_id),
  }
}
```

My question is. Is this an issue of how GetCorrelationId creates the GUID object or there is something wrong with the configuration of the framework?

The framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1
We see this issue in IIS Express and IIS server

I can't share code but I'll do my best to share as much information is needed to troubleshoot this issue.

This are some examples of duplicates GUID

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution. I'm posting it so if someone else has the same issue can get this example.

After some more digging on Google I found this post
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392926/Grouping-application-traces-using-ActivityId

Sebastian is using the ActivityId generated by IIS to tied together the different commands executed during his process.

Then I found the source code of HttpRequestMessageExtensions https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs

There, you can see that the method GetCorrelationId() uses the ActivityId to assign a correlation ID to the request.

ActivityId is not completely random. It is tied to the thread started by IIS. I notice that all our request from localhost:port have the same string at the end `b63f-84710c7967bb`.

We wanted to tied all the commands executed to save an object or retrieve it. So all we needed was a random Guid generated per request. Following the example posted by Sebastian, I stored the current ActivityId in an aux variable, then assigned a new GUID to it, executed Request.GetCorrelationId() and finally assigned back the ID stored in the aux variable to the ActivityId.

In pseudo code =>

```
Guid prevActivityId = Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid()
...

guid correlation_id = Request.GetCorrelationId()

...
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = prevActivityId
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else.

Comment: I'm not selecting this answer as the best answer because it works for our case only as far as I know. Maybe some else with more knowledge on how the ActivityId gets generated can expand on this.